# Grammatical complements for "allow"

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives, gerunds, complements

Are any of these verb phrases grammatical?

> - allows the user of modeling and resolving
> - allows the user to model and resolve

Which version of the following sentence is correct/better?

> - In particular, it **allows to acquire** a signal using a sample rate significantly lower than the one dictated by the Nyquist criterion.
> - In particular, it **allows acquiring** a signal using a sample rate
>     significantly lower than the one dictated by the Nyquist criterion.

I searched Google Scholar for "[allows to acquire](http://bit.ly/T04nd3)" and "[allows acquiring](http://bit.ly/YbZEnI)", and it seems people use both more or less with the same frequency.

Comment: You will find information about the usage of the verb *allow* in the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/allow).

Comment: The second is grammatical, the first  is not. _Allow_ takes an infinitive complement, not a gerund.

Comment: I agree. A list is not the way to approach this, and this list is not categorized by constituents.

Comment: I am sorry to ask a weird question out of the topic here, is the sentence above "Are any of these verb phrases grammatical?" pretty normal and natural? I am a ESL learner but it sounds awkward to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The semantics of the verb *allow* meaning "permit" has three arguments, making it a [trivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_(linguistics)) verb. Using the linguistic terminology for [thematic relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_relation), there is the entity that is granting the permission (the agent), the entity that receives the permission (the patient), and the thing that is permitted (the theme).

The verb *allow* can be used in three different syntactic constructions which explicitly indicate what is allowed (the theme). Here are the three constructions with examples from the Corpus of Contemporary American English:

(a) with a gerund complement indicating what is allowed: *allow [gerund phrase]*

> the president last month unveiled plans to **allow** [drilling in Atlantic waters from Virginia to mid-Florida]
>
> Sets up Web portals that standardize policies and **allow** [purchasing across state lines]

Note that in this construct, the verb does not include an object indicating the entity which is being allowed, nor is the gerund complement introduced with *of*, as in the first example from the question. This would be grammatical, though:

> Allows modeling and resolving

(b) with just a noun phrase object indicating what is allowed: *allow [noun phrase]*

> and are working with the school administrators to **allow** [use of personal devices in our schools].
>
> The learning commons has extended its hours of operation to **allow** [more access to its physical space].

(c) with a noun phrase object (indicating the patient) and an infinitive complement (indicating the theme):  *allow [noun phrase] [infinitive phrase]*

This is the only construct where all three arguments to the verb can be expressed together.

> we're not going to **allow** [them] [to disrupt this debate and take the focus off the real issue here].
>
> Certainly parents who **allow** [their children] [to consume violent entertainment products] do share some of the responsibility.
>
> These tools and resources **allow** [you] [to connect, communicate, collaborate, and create].

Note that the recipient of the allowance (the patient) isn't always a person or person-like entity:

> Only nine states **allow** [life-sustaining treatment] [to be withheld from patients in a persistent vegetative state].

Note also that this constructions *requires* both a direct object and an infinitive complement. The verb *allow* cannot be used with just an infinitive complement; that is, constructions like "allow to [verb]" are ungrammatical. The following examples which I found via Google are clearly written by non-native speakers and are not grammatical:

> * What smartphone allows to connect my computer to it for surfing ?
>
> * Image drag and drop allows to create executable files
>
> * Will java allow to use functional interfaces as methods?

Comment: I don't like the sound of 'allows acquiring' - I'd want allows (or perhaps enables here) the acquisition of. However, _allows fishing_ and, as you say, _allows purchasing across state lines_, are fine. Probably, this is connected with the different senses of _allow_ - grant permission and make possible.

Comment: how would you rephrase 3 last sentences without changing the meaning?

Answer (score 5):

Only the second is correct as written.

However, "allows us to acquire", "allows one to acquire", "allows the system to acquire" and so on are all also valid.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain me why? How is "allows the system to acquire" different than "allows it to acquire"? In my mind "it" just replaces "the system".

Comment: You don't have "allows it to acquire" in the above, you have "allows to acquire". "It allows it to acquire" is valid, as long as both uses of *it* refer to the same thing. (If there's a different thing referred to by each *it* then it's syntactically valid, but likely to cause confusion).

Comment: You're right! Thanks again. So in general "allows <noun/pronoun> to acquire" is correct?

Comment: Yes. "[Noun/pronoun/gerund1] allows [noun/pronoun2] to acquire" means the first thing allows the second thing to acquire something. It's worth avoiding two *it*s if those are different things, to avoid confusion.

Comment: "Allows acquiring" is correct, but it sounds awkward to me.

Comment: I'd prefer "allows the acquisition of ..." to "allows acquiring", although both are grammatical.